# Angular UI TinyMCE , how to setup print feature

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce-4

I am using angular ui tinymce extension. I would like to know how do I set the print feature to show on the editor. I have tried adding the print feature, however the editor itself does not show up either. Here is my html:

```
 <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" name="template_content" ng-model="templateDocument.content"></textarea>
```

Here is the JavaScript configuration for the editor:

```
  $scope.tinymceOptions = {
        inline: false,
        plugins : ['code lists preview paste pagebreak advlist wordcount print'],
        skin: 'lightgray',
        theme : 'modern',
        trusted: true,
        height: 500,
        format: 'raw',
        menubar: true,
        toolbar: [
          "undo redo paste | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | pagebreak | code preview"
        ]
      };
```

When I remove print from the plugin property, the editor is shows up. What am I doing wrong in the editor configuration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What JavaScript errors do you get in the console when trying to load this init?  Typically if loading a plugin causes your init to fail it is because that plugin is not in the location TinyMCE expects to find the code.

For example, the print plugin is in a folder named `print` within the TinyMCE `plugins` folder.  When you try to load TinyMCE and the print plugin the editor will look in that location by default.  If I purposefully remove the print plugin from my TinyMCE installation I get this during the editor load process:

```
Failed to load: 
http://localhost/.../editors/tinymce_4.3.10/tinymce/plugins/print/plugin.js
```

So if simply adding the `print` plugin to the init causes this to fail I would start by

- Looking at the JavaScript console to see if there are errors
- Look in the `plugins` folder within TinyMCE to see if the print folder is there